How to refresh few columns in Big Query Pivoted Table
I have a Big Query Pivoted table created using Big Query PIVOT functionality as below
CREATE PIVOT_TABLE
PARTITION BY <COLUMN1>
AS 

WITH TEST AS
(
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN1 between 'DATE1' and 'DATE2')
  PIVOT (SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT, SUM(QUANTITY) as QUANTITY FOR METRIC_NM IN ('SALES', 'WAGES'))
)
SELECT * FROM TEST ;

Sample table Output:
enter image description here
Now Once Pivot table is created out of a base table initially, later incremental refresh is needed only for one metric Sales. Is there a possibility to refresh only columns AMOUNT_SALES and QUANTITY_SALES related to Sales metric for any given day in pivoted table?
Did not find a direct way to refresh few columns in pivoted table unless you do a DELETE and INSERT into Pivoted table for all metrics for refreshed day. This is possible if I am maintaining entire data in base table.
But in my case I am not planning to maintain a permanent base table as that contains huge redundant data. In this case, how do I refresh only subset of metrics?
The option I tried is to UNPIVOT from Pivoted table, refresh needed metric and again do an INSERT INTO Pivoted table for the entire day. But this did not work for me.
This is the output I am expecting
enter image description here
